# php crosscompile ARM processor running Linux

Tags: php, arm, cross-compiling

I have cross-compiled PHP5.2.13 for ARM processor running Linux. Following is the commands I used:-

1. export PATH=/usr/local/DigiEL-5.9/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/bin:$PATH
   /usr/local/DigiEL-5.9/x-tools/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi/sysroot/usr/
2. CC=arm-linux-gcc ./configure --host=arm-linux --prefix=/usr --without-iconv --disable-xml --without-pear --disable-libxml --disable-dom --disable-simplexml --disable-xmlreader --disable-xmlwriter
3. make INSTALL_ROOT=$HOME/phpinstall install

On the target Machine I have executed the following command
`scp test@sourceIP:/home/test/phpinstall/usr/bin/* ./`

Now on the target machine executed `cd /usr/bin`
I could see the php, php-cgi, php-conf,phpize files.
I have the environment path as well.
But when I executed php -v. it throws the following error.

> /usr/bin/php: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I checked in Google but invain

Comment: Thank You Peter for formatting, Initial Format was lost after posting and I couldn't reformat.

Comment: Finally, it worked.  Just added few more parameters to 'Make' command and it worked.  make HOSTCC=gcc CXX=arm-linux-c++ CC=arm-linux-gcc

Answer (score 0):

use  'make HOSTCC=gcc CXX=arm-linux-c++ CC=arm-linux-gcc' instead of using 'make' alone followed by 'make INSTALL_ROOT=$HOME/phpinstall install'. Now copy the php, php-cgi files into the target machine. Set the path
export PATH=usr/bin:$PATH.
Test :
execute php-cgi -v command. from /usr/bin directory. 
Example /usr/bin # php-cgi -v. 
Output :
PHP 5.4.0 (cgi-fcgi) (built: Jul 26 2017 09:07:16)
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group